# The alpha range in LassoCV

Tags: python, scikit-learn, lasso-regression

I’m using LassoCV to establish model. I noticed that the code automatically set the alpha (lambda in paper Friedman, Hastie & Tibshirani (2010)). Basically, the range calculated codes are the same as the lambda calculation in the paper. However, it returns the log10 (alpha_max). I don't why the code uses log10. It sharply reduced the range of alpha.

```
 return np.logspace(np.log10(alpha_max * eps), np.log10(alpha_max),
                       num=n_alphas)[::-1]
```

Comment: When I viewed the question, I find the answer... This code uses 'logspace'. That's why inside using 'log10'. After (logspace(log10 (A)), the value is still A. It is the same as described by paper (Friedman, Hastie & Tibshirani (2010)).